# KY040 Rotary Encoder not responding at all

Tags: gpio, raspbian-jessie

Hey I'm very new to raspberry pi and decided to start a mall project including a rotary encoder.

I found some guides online that I followed but I just can't get any signal from the encoder transmitted to my python script.

Here's the simple python script:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

CLOCKPIN = 5
DATAPIN = 6
SWITCHPIN = 13

def rot(dir):
  print("rotation: %" % dir)

def press():
  print("pressed")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
  GPIO.setup(CLOCKPIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
  GPIO.setup(DATAPIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
  GPIO.setup(SWITCHPIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

  counter = 0
  clkLastState = GPIO.input(CLOCKPIN)
  swtLastState = GPIO.input(SWITCHPIN)

  print("start messing around...")

  try:
    while True:
      clkState = GPIO.input(CLOCKPIN)
      dtState = GPIO.input(DATAPIN)
      swtState = GPIO.input(SWITCHPIN)
      if clkState != clkLastState:
        if dtState != clkState:
          counter += 1
        else:
          counter -= 1
      if swtState != swtLastState:
        print("click")
        time.sleep(1.0)
      print(counter)
      clkLastState = clkState
      time.sleep(0.05)
  finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

when I check the GPIOs with ". gpiotest" I get:

```
Testing...
Pull up on gpio 30 failed.
Skipped non-user gpios:
Tested user gpios: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22     23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
Failed user gpios: 30
```

And finally here are pictures how I connected the encoder with the gpios:

[image]

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi, from your photos it looks like the problem is that you've forgotten to connect the Raspberry Pi to the GPIO pins :) .

Answer (score 0):

What model Pi?  pigpio seems to think GPIO 0-31 are all valid.

I would change all the

`pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN`

to

`pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP`

I don't know the module you are using but mechanical rotary encoders typically pull to ground and float to the external voltage.  Unless the module has its own pull-ups you need the Pi GPIO to be normally pulled up.

If that doesn't work could you see what [monitor.py](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_monitor_py) reports.

Comment: Sorry forgot about that.
Its a Raspberry pi zero w with Raspian Jessie
The Rotary is the KY040

Comment: I made the changes yu suggested but I still can't get a signal.
The monitor.py gives me somthing like this:

`[...]
G=6 l=1 d=8701
G=13 l=1 d=9240
G=14 l=1 d=9455
G=5 l=0 d=11315
G=6 l=0 d=11325
G=13 l=0 d=10781
G=14 l=0 d=10565
G=5 l=1 d=8710
G=6 l=1 d=8700
G=13 l=1 d=9294
G=14 l=1 d=9435
G=5 l=0 d=11359
G=6 l=0 d=11329
G=13 l=0 d=10726
G=13 l=1 d=5
G=13 l=0 d=5
G=14 l=0 d=10581
G=5 l=1 d=8780
G=6 l=1 d=8775
G=13 l=1 d=9324
G=14 l=1 d=9459
[...]`

Comment: That could well be the encoder pulses.  Could you get a screenshot with piscope? http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html

Comment: The KY040 has pull ups for the rotary, mine has 10K and a spot to add one resistor for the push button. You can check it with a meter to see if it is working.